# Using CsvHelper, How to map to a second column, if the value of the first column equals 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csv, csvhelper

Is there a way to map to a second field, if the first field is less than 0?

For example, if you are mapping a csv file with columns `foo` and `bar`:

```
Map(m => m.Price).Name("foo");
```

And if the column `foo` equals 0, can we then map `Price` to the value of the `bar` column instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to manually convert the column like below.

```
Map(x => x.Price)
    .Name("foo")
    .ConvertUsing(row =>
    {
        var fooValue = row.GetField<decimal>("foo");

        if (fooValue == 0m)
        {
            return row.GetField<decimal>("bar");
        }
        return fooValue;
    });
```

That said, I don't think you should be using CsvHelper to do conditional mapping.  Ideally, you'd have a mapping for your CSV model and another model you want to map to.  Then have code that maps your CSV model to that other model.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem, and the advice. That makes sense about having a separate CSV model that maps to my main model.